# Web Crawler Exercise of Go Tour - get stuck and only able to crawl the first website

Tags: go

Web Crawler exercise comes right after the illustration of mutex usage. So I created a visited map and used mutex to protect it. However below code implementation not work, and it only crawl the first / entrance website. Anyone knows why?

```
type SafeMap struct{
    m map[string]bool
    mux sync.Mutex
}

func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, visited SafeMap) {
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        visited.mux.Lock()
        if visited.m[u] != true {
            visited.m[u] = true
            go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, visited)
        }
        visited.mux.Unlock()
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    visited := SafeMap{m: make(map[string]bool)}
    visited.m["https://golang.org/"] = true
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, visited)
}

var fetcher = fakeFetcher{ going from "https://golang.org/" to a lots of websites }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program ends before the goroutines complete. You should wait for them. Use a waitgroup:

```
func main() {
    visited := &SafeMap{m: make(map[string]bool)}
    visited.m["https://golang.org/"] = true
    wg:=sync.WaitGroup{}
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, visited,&wg)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Crawl:

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, visited *SafeMap, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
   wg.Add(1)
   defer wg.Done()
   ...
}
```

Comment: I have run this code. It also only crawl the first url

Comment: You are passing the SafeMap, and hence the mutex, by value. Pass it by reference. Add some logging to see what Crawl is doing